# CSS3 flex-box property

Tags: css, flexbox

I wanted to use flex box property to my layout where we create boxes dynamically.

So I want to adjust themselves(box) as per the count. Like if only 1 box is there, it should take complete 100% space and max 3 boxes will come in one row. 
If 4th box comes in the screen then go to the next row automatically.

I have searched a lot about flex-flow but did not get the right solution.

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Using new syntax, Chrome (requires prefix) and Opera only at present:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#container > * {
    flex: 1 1 33%;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lpd_/qwwT8/. If you don't want items on subsequent rows to stretch once the first row is filled, you can add:

```
#container > *:nth-child(n+4) {
    max-width: 33.33%;
    max-width: calc(100% / 3); /* To override and be more precise, if you wish */
}
```